# Sign of a permutation

Tags: group-theory

http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/~montanar/presentations/matchings.pdf

I'm reading this, but I forgot some group theory.

How is 
$sgn((2,1,4,3))=1$ and $sgn((3,2,1,4))=-1$.

Isn't

$(2,1,4,3)=(2,1)(2,4)(2,3)$

So how is that even possible. Also, isn't $(2,1,4,3)=(3,2,1,4)$. Help really confused.

Comment: $sgn(2,1,4,3)=-1$ definitely, probably a typo.

Comment: Must be a typo. The sign of any cycle of $2k$ terms is $-1$. My guess is that the typo is the inclusion of an extra term in the cycle and that they purposely wanted to show something with sign $+1$.

Comment: (2, 1, 4, 3) and (3, 2, 1, 4) are being considered as 4-tuples of numbers - permutations of (1, 2, 3, 4). To get to (2, 1, 4, 3) from (1, 2, 3, 4), you apply the permutation (1 2)(3 4), which has sign 1. It's awful notation.

Comment: The other commenters already answered the question. But I do not think the splitting you wrote holds. Consider the product $(2,1)(2,4)(2,3)$, by applying it to $(1,2,3,4)$ you get $(1,3,2,4)$, then $(1,3,4,2)$, then $(2,3,4,1)$. This is different from $(2,1,4,3)$.

Answer (score 2):

The notation (2,1,4,3) is not meant to be cycle notation, but instead it's indicating the permutation $1 \mapsto 2, 2 \mapsto 1, 3 \mapsto 4, 4 \mapsto 3$, which does have sign +1.  Similarly, (3,2,1,4) is $1 \mapsto 3, 2 \mapsto 2, 3 \mapsto 1, 4 \mapsto 4$, which has sign -1.